# Помогите с записью JSON файла

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, discord

Я занимаюсь разработкой бота на discord.js, я пытаюсь дополнить файл json, но у меня не выходит

Мой код:

```
text = {[message.author.id]:{"text":[args.slice(1).join(' ');]}}
   
fs.appendFile(pathClan, JSON.stringify(text, null, 4), err => {
  if(err) console.log(err)
});
```

Что выходит в JSON файле

```
{
    "айди пользователя #1": {
        "text": "текст пользователя #1"
    }
}{
    "айди пользователя #2": {
        "text": "текст пользователя #2"
    }
}
```

А как получить

```
{
    "айди пользователя #1": {
        "text": "текст пользователя #1"
    },
    "айди пользователя #2": {
        "text": "текст пользователя #2"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы производите добавление на уровне файла, а не на уровне объекта-json.
Вам нужно считать объект из исходного файла, добавить туда новые данные и выгрузить обновленный объект в файл.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const pathClan = "file.json";

let rawdata = fs.readFileSync(pathClan);
let users = JSON.parse(rawdata);

let user = {"айди пользователя #2": {
        "text": "текст пользователя #2"
    }};

users = {...users, ...user};

fs.writeFile(pathClan, JSON.stringify(users, null, 4), err => {
  if(err) console.log(err)
});
```

Comment: Это работает, но данный код обновляет уже имеющиеся данные, а мне бы хотелось что бы он дописывал новые данные, что бы при использование команды, он создавал новый блок с новыми значениями

Comment: @ДенисВоронин других вариантов c json нет. если тебе нужно "дописывание" то нужно менять подход, например, делать "клан" каталогом с файлами и каждого пользователя писать в `"айди пользователя #2".json`. или менять формат хранения данных, слёту, - yaml вполне подходит для appendFile. или хранить данные в БД. для файлового подхода не забудь, что будет логичным заморочиться с удалением члена клана, без полного изменения файла, что тоже решаемо, но немного заморочено

Comment: Я понял, спасибо

Comment: Тогда проще будет делать файл для каждого пользователя, тогда возникает вопрос как изменить одно значение из массы других ?

Comment: ты имеешь ввиду «изменить один параметр для каждого пользователя клана»? ровно так же как в ответе - читаешь каждый файл полностью, пишешь каждый файл полностью. в общем, так себе идея хранить в файлах. если тебе хочется файлов - сделай один json базой данных, с делай к нему интерфейс, общайся не с файлом, а с интерфейсом, периодически синхронизируй данные на диск